# AJAX call with jQuery + Coffeescript not generated correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have the following Coffeescript:

```
$(document).ready ->`
        $.ajax 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1285016',
               type: 'GET'
               dataType: 'json'
               error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) -> $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"          
               success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) -> $('body').append "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
```

However this genrates the following Javascript which doesn't look right to me:

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $.ajax('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1285016');
  });

  ({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      return $('body').append("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      return $('body').append("Successful AJAX call: " + data);
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

Can anyone tell me where this is going wrong?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: your code is working fine on coffeescript.org (minus that `)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't compile your current code (`CoffeeScript version 1.6.1`), but if you remove the `` ` `` symbol after `$(document).ready ->` it compiles to

```
(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $.ajax('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1285016', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return $('body').append("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return $('body').append("Successful AJAX call: " + data);
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

---

I'm not sure how `CoffeeScript` handles line breaks, but I guess you're compiling a file with `Windows end-of-lines` (`CRLF`) on a `*nix` system and that causes the problem.

I'm saying that because something like the following code:

```
 $(document).ready ->

        $.ajax 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1285016',

      type: 'GET'

      dataType: 'html'

      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) -> $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"

      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) -> $('body').append "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
```

compiles to the one you've posted. (note that there is a line-break on line 3 after `,`)

Comment: Thanks, ended up being a problem with my text editor leaving whitespace behind